# Why doesn't my service start?

Tags: android, android-service

I use an AlarmManager to start a service, but for some reason I can't figure out the service isn't starting.

The code in my onResume() for starting the service is:

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(cxt, NotificationService.class);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent penIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.cancel(penIntent);

            penIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    10 * 1000, penIntent);
```

The Manifest contains the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
     android:debuggable="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/icon"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <service
          android:name="de.brillow.mensa.Speiseplan$NotificationService"
          android:enabled="true" />
```

And finally the service itself looks like this:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

        private WakeLock mWakeLock;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // obtain the wake lock
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    "wakelocktag");
            mWakeLock.acquire();

            Log.i("PowerManager", "acquired");

            // do the actual work, in a separate thread
            new PollTask().execute();
        }

        private class PollTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // do stuff!
                Log.i("Background", "stuff");
                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // handle your data
                int id = 001;
                Log.i("Noti", "fication");
                NotificationManager mNotifyMng = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        Speiseplan.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Test").setContentText("Test!");

                mNotifyMng.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                Log.i("Notification", "sent");
                stopSelf();
                Log.i("Service", "stopped");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            handleIntent(intent);
        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            handleIntent(intent);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }


        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
```

For some reason neither the notification nor the Log.i-message shows up. I hope you can help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an `AsyncTask` inside of a `Service`. `AsyncTask` should only be used for tasks that *return a result into the current activity*, i.e. it should be defined in an `Activity` or `Fragment`. That is what it is designed for.

In your case, you can put everything from `doInBackground(...)` and `onPostExecute(...)` into `onCreate(...)` of your service. Use a Thread if you want. If you need to visualize your service results in an `Activity`, invoke an `Intent` and pass any details into extras, e.g.

Invocation in service ...

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,VisualizingActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("A", "Data A");
intent.putExtra("B", "Data B");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Processing in activity ...

```
String A= intent.getStringExtra("A");
String B= intent.getStringExtra("B");
```

If you just want to create `Notification`s you can do that from the service directly. There's no need for an `AsyncTask` or `Activity`.

Hope this helps a bit ... Cheers!

Comment: It helped a little, thanks. But it doesn't solve my problem. The service (as badly coded as it may be) dooesn't even start...

Comment: 1. remove the `AsyncTask`; 2. declare the service in the Manifest: `android:name="de.brillow.mensa.NotificationService"`; 3. start your servive from somewhere: `Intent service = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class); context.startService(service);`

Comment: THAT was the mistake I made. I put the Service inside my main activity .java file. Putting it in a new file and making the adjustments you mentioned it now starts, thanks a lot!